# Tap controller implementation in JTAG

Tags: jtag

I’m looking at a  TAP controller for the implementation of JTAG, but I’m not sure what which part of the diagram the top left circuit is refeering to.

Are the boundary scan cells just D-flip flops?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item in the top left of the graphic looks very similar to the boundary scan register ell from the JTAG standard, IEEE 1149.1 figure 1-1.

[image]

Each cell consists of two muxes and 2 D-flip-flops.  A group of boundary scan register cells are arranged into a boundary scan register.  Data moves serially from one cell to the next like a big shift register.

- Setting Shift/Load = 0 and toggling clock A will load the left flip-flop in each cell with the pin value.
- Setting Shift/Load = 1 and toggling clock A will shift the captured data through each boundary scan cell, and eventually out of TDO so you can read it.  You can also shift new data in via TDI that will can be loaded into the output registers.
- Toggling clock B can load right-most flip-flop in each boundary scan cell with the data from the left most one.  This data can then be put onto the pin if the right-most mux selects that it should be put there.
- The right most mux selects weather the the pin value is controlled by the device under test, or if it is driven by the output flip-flop.

Per IEEE 1149.1-2001 page 21 in the description for the Shift-DR state,
Clock A is supposed to toggle once every time TCK toggles and the TAP state machine is in the Shift DR-state, and the boundary scan register is selcted.

CLOCK_A <= TCK when state=shift_dr and bs_reg_selcted = '1'  else '0';

Per IEEE 1149.1-2001 page 21 in the description for the Capture-DR state,
Clock B is supposed to toggle once every time TCK toggles and the TAP state machine is in the Capture-DR state, and the boundary scan register is selcted.

CLOCK_B <= TCK when state = capture_dr and bs_reg_selcted = '1' else '0';

Comment: Thanks why exactly are there 2 clocks?

Comment: There are two clocks, because there are two sets of flip-flops to be controlled.  Clock B is only toggled when you want to update outputs.  Clock A is toggled to either capture inputs, or shift data through the boundary scan registers.  One could just as easily use one clock and two clock enables.

Comment: Are clocks continuous? is one faster than the other?

Comment: They are not continuous.  They are gated versions of TCK depending on what satate the TAP controller is in.  Clock B toggles once when you are in the capture DR state.  Clock A toggles only when you are in the shift DR state and shifting out/in pin data through the boundary scan registers.